# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: object. Error 500 in React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

At startup it gives error 500:
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You probably forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Git of the project: https://github.com/MelnikVladyslav/ProxySeller

Tried to see if Webpack is configured correctly